# Delphi - Equivalent ListBox string search for ListView

Tags: listview, delphi, search, firemonkey

`ListBox` have a very easy way to search for a string inside it:

```
if ListBox1.Items.IndexOf('yourString') > -1 then
begin
  //arriba
end;
```

Is there an equivalent way to search for a `string` but using `ListView`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`FindCaption`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TCustomListView_FindCaption.html) method of `TListView`.

Comment: I'm using `Firemonkey`. It looks like this method does not exist.

Comment: @tardoandre You should have said so in your question.

Comment: I have been putting it on almost every question and people are always removing the tag.

Comment: You should say so in the question itself, not just tag it with [firemonkey]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're searching for Swissdelphicenter seems to have a quick solution [Link to the article](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/de/showcode.php?id=947)

> Call FindCaption Method to search for a list view item labeled by the
>     string specified as the Value parameter

I'm not a FMX expert but cant you use:

FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.SearchVisible

for more details use this [Link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.SearchVisible)

> Shows a search box on top of your list view that can filter the content of the list.

Comment: I would rather search for it without using a `loop` statement. Thus, `SearchVisible` is for searching ListItems. I want to search for strings inside the List to avoid adding duplicated items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
procedure SarchLV(SearchStr: String);
begin

  SearchStr := LowerCase(SearchStr);

  ListView1.Items.Filter :=
    Function(X: string): Boolean
    Begin
       Result:= (SearchStr = EmptyStr) Or LowerCase(X).Contains(SearchStr);
     End;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

So create helper. In form unit:

```
THelperListView = class helper for TListView
public
  function FindCaption(const aText: string): boolean;
end;

function THelperListView.FindCaption(const aText: string): boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  for i := 0 to Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Result := CompareText(Items[i].Text, aText) = 0;
    if Result then
      exit;
  end;
end;
```